# How to view MS office files online in asp.net 4.0, C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I am working on a file management system which developed in C# & ASP.NET where user can store bulk files. Now I want to view all viewable formats of file (i.e. image, ms office, pdf etc) open in browser (without downloading in clients local machine). I have already done half of my job i.e. my application is working fine for all image files and pdf files. But I am facing problems with ms office files (i.e. `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.doc`, `.docx`, `.ppt`, etc.) formats. I tried some piece of code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the appropriate ContentType.
        string FilePath = MapPath("Test/xyz.pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + "xyz.pdf" + "\"");
        Response.Write(FilePath);
        Response.End();
    }
```

This code works fine only for `.pdf` files but when I changed my content type `Response.ContentType` for word or excel files `Application/msword` (for Microsoft Word files) `Application/x-msexcel` (for Microsoft Excel files) then this code not works.
Please guide me what can I do. Should I use any tool like google documents viewer or some thing else.If it is possible only with tool then please suggest me a good tool for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Andry for correcting me.

Comment: Did you find an answer?  Please accept a solution or provide one yourself if you did.  I have same issue and maybe others do as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
Response.ContentType = application/force-download
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=filename.xls
```

Also for excel I'm seeing some people use: `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"` however your MIME for MS Word seems to be good.

Also [here is a link](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php) to all of the MIME types for MS Office 2007+

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing this software where you can control the browser usage, which is to say you can dictate which browser the users make use of, you can try this component http://www.ocxt.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "test.xls";
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/test.xls");
    Response.Clear();

    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```